# Javascript - TypeError: loadData.getData is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fetching json file format from url, But I want the function inside of a class, but I got an undefined thing on output, here's all my codes:

```
const axios = require('axios');

var BASE_URL = 'https://estra-api.herokuapp.com/'


class loadData {
    constructor() {
        self.sfw = {};
        self.nsfw = {};
    }
    getData(){
        axios.get(BASE_URL)
        .then(function data (response) {
            return response.data["link"]
        })
    }
}
console.log(loadData.getData())
```

My Output errors was

```
console.log(loadData.getData())
                     ^

TypeError: loadData.getData is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Stawa\Desktop\EstraMainAPI\EstraJS-API\index.js:20:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

I have tried to use `console.log(loadData.getData)` it just give me output `undefined`

Comment: `console.log((new loadData()).getData())`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should look like this:

```
new loadData().getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

loadData is a class. Means that you need to init this class before you read properties of their. like that:

```js
class loadData {
    constructor() {
        self.sfw = {};
        self.nsfw = {};
    }
    getData(){
        axios.get(BASE_URL)
        .then(function data (response) {
            return response.data["link"]
        })
    }
}

const ld = new loadData()
console.log(ld.getData())
```